# Error: The method where(String) is undefined while using spring boot mongodb

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, changestream

I have added the mongodb dependencies in my spring boot app however I am getting undefined error on "where" method:

```
ChangeStreamRequest<Person> request = ChangeStreamRequest.builder()
    .collection("person")
    .filter(newAggregation(Person.class, match(where("operationType").is("insert"))))
    .publishTo(pListener)
    .build();
```

POM configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Please advise me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for "undefined" is "there is no method `where` defined in your class".

You have to import `where` method from `Criteria`.

You can use `Criteria.where("operationType").is("insert")` by adding the below import statement.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
```

Alternatively you can add a static import as below:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;
```

Now, you can directly use :

```
where("operationType").is("insert")
```

Comment: Thank you, it is difficult to find the references of static methods